# Django: Old url is still searched after POST request

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am fairly new to Django.

I have changed the url name from 'odata' to 'database' and the app properly redirects to the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/. However while being at http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/ and making the POST request using ajax, the app freezes and on looking in the browser's developer tools I see the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/odata/
.
.
.
The current path, odata/, didn't match any of these.
```

Why the old name is still being searched?

I have made changes in the following files and codes:
my_app/url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view1, name = "view1"),
    path('database/', views.view2, name = "view2"), #old name was odata/
   
]
```

myreq.js

```
   function submit_training() {
       $.ajax({
       url: '/database/', //earlier- /odata/
       data: $('form#db_settings').serialize(),
       method: 'POST',
       ...
   }
```

When I revert the changes to 'odata' everything works as expected. I am not sure what I am missing here.

I apologize for not providing more or exact codes, as I am not supposed to disclose details on the project. However, I can still furnish more information, if required.

Comment: save urls.py file and restart your development server.

Comment: This looks like a cache issue, try using your browser in incognito mode and restarting the browser. I sometimes just restart my machine when I see problems like this because it's easier than searching every possible cache and clearing them.

Comment: Restarting the machine did not help. Same error as before :(